# How to float all child divs to center inside a parent div?

Tags: html, css-float, center

i use a parent div with three child divs ,

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="PagerUp" class="pager">

     </div>
    <div id="ResultsDiv">

    </div>
    <div id="PagerDown" class="pager">

    </div>
</div>
```

But what i get is this http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/5923/floatingdivs.jpg

How to float all those divs to center.... Hint:I dint apply any css...

Comment: For what its worth, I think it looks better left aligned :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#parentDiv {
  width: 600px; /* or whatever width you specify */
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

.

## Update:

Try giving margins to the pagers:

```
#PagerUp, #PagerDown
{
      width: 600px; /* or whatever width you specify */
      margin:0px auto;
}
```

Or you can do like this too:

```
#PagerUp, #PagerDown
{
   width: 600px; /* or whatever width you specify */
   margin-left:100px;  /* adjust value accordingly */
   margin-right:100px;  /* adjust value accordingly */
}
```

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: Could you elaborate little more what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @sarfraz i want then to look like this http://img151.imageshack.us/img151/5594/centerddiv.jpg

Comment: @sarfraz pager div postion in center above and below resultsdiv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center all those div, then you must center their parent.
Use
margin:0 auto
on #parentDiv